# How to do DNS record verification for validating domain to be used with Mailgun?

Tags: dns, mailgun, squarespace

I want to use my domain with Mailgun. After registering my domain (hosted by SquareSpace) with Mailgun, it asks me to enter the required DNS record in my domain's setting. I am just wondering if I have entered them correctly inside SquareSpace's terminal

Here's what Mailgun wants: 
[image]

And here's what I've entered in SquareSpace's setting: 
[image]

I've never done this before, so I'm wondering if I've entered it in the right place?

Answer (score 2):

I've finally solved the problem. Apparently squarespace doesn't want us to enter our domain name in the hostname column.

So instead of inputting clidev.net, I had to input @.
Instead of inputting smtp._domainkey.clidev.net, I had to input smtp._domainkey

Now everything works.

Thank you all for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Yep those are correct based off what they gave you

Comment: It turns out that square space requires users to input @ instead of the domain name (clidev.net) for it to work. Unfortunately, I still couldn't get the 2nd one to work, the one with hostname starting with smtp. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: A dig on your record yields 
`smtp._domainkey.clidev.net. 14400 IN TXT "k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDVCCpZutTJgovFPWJwXm+GMnOLw54pveLfpRInPKZ+wKk/z3GJ23f1evRRRdDZ8QRU/+Xd4hKPsP4Ikn0fgc4zdzoHGiuqKi69qIxsWspCAW2QI5E44Z5ZMVpEjZ1E5lsLiJEANiAnHpJkk2m+88z24ti1ht7DEr8TODshSDW6QQIDAQAB"`

mailgun is likely looking for two distinct records, one for k=..., and one for p=..., having multiple txt with the same name is legal in dns so I would try replacing that with two records, one for each